# Micronaut security fails to "secure"

Tags: java, security, micronaut

I have a simple Micronaut- based "hello world" service that has a simple security built in (for the sake of testing and illustrating the Micronaut security). The controller code in the service that implements the hello service is provided below:

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController
{
   public HelloController()
   {
      // Might put some stuff in in the future
   }

    @Get("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index()
    {
       return("Hello to the World of Micronaut!!!");
    }
}
```

In order to test the security mechanism, I have followed the Micronaut tutorial instructions and created a security service class:

```
@Singleton
public class SecurityService
{
    public SecurityService()
    {
       // Might put in some stuff in the future
    }

    Flowable<Boolean> checkAuthorization(HttpRequest<?> theReq)
    {
        Flowable<Boolean> flow = Flowable.fromCallable(()->{
           System.out.println("Security Engaged!");
           return(false);    <== The tutorial says return true
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

        return(flow);
    }

}
```

It should be noted that, in a departure from the tutorial, the flowable.fromCallable() lambda returns false. In the tutorial, it returns true. I had assumed that a security check would fail if a false is returned, and that a failure would cause the hello service to fail to respond.

According to the tutorials, in ordeer to begin using the Security object, it is necessary to have a filter. The filter I created is shown below:

```
@Filter("/**")
public class HelloFilter implements HttpServerFilter
{
   private final SecurityService secService;

   public HelloFilter(SecurityService aSec)
   {
      System.out.println("Filter Created!");
      secService = aSec;
   }

   @Override
   public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> theReq, ServerFilterChain theChain)
   {
      System.out.println("Filtering!");
      Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> resp = secService.checkAuthorization(theReq)
                                                         .doOnNext(res->{
                                                            System.out.println("Responding!");
                                                         });

      return(resp);
   }
}
```

The problem occurs when I run the microservice and access the Helo world URL. (http://localhost:8080/hello) I cannot cause the access to the service to fail. The filter catches all requests, and the security object is engaged, but it does not seem to prevent access to the hello service. I do not know what it takes to make the access fail.

Can someone help on this matter? Thank you.

Comment: "According to the tutorials, in ordeer to begin using the Security object, it is necessary to have a filter. The filter I created is shown below" - To which tutorial are you referring?  In general you don't need to write your own filter to use security but maybe there is some context in that tutorial which makes that claim make more sense.

Comment: FYI... We have published several security related guides at http://guides.micronaut.io/tags/security.html.  JWT will be a popular choice for a lot of REST services: http://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-security-jwt/guide/index.html

Comment: Jeff: I had read the doco in the links you provided prior to attempting to use filters. They were not relevant to what I am trying to do. When I write a server these days (any server, not just microservices) I like to build in something that acts as an interceptor for all requests that come in. This approach allows me to better modularize crosscutting concerns. In Micronaut filters act a lot like interceptors. That is why I chose the filter approach instead of the ones provided in your referenced documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change request in your filter when you no have access to resource or process request as usual. Your HelloFilter looks like this:

```
@Override
public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> theReq, ServerFilterChain theChain) {
    System.out.println("Filtering!");
    Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> resp = secService.checkAuthorization(theReq)
            .switchMap((authResult) -> { // authResult - is you result from SecurityService
                if (!authResult) {
                    return Publishers.just(HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)); // reject request
                } else {
                    return theChain.proceed(theReq); // process request as usual
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(res -> {
                System.out.println("Responding!");
            });

    return (resp);
}
```

And in the last - micronaut has security module with SecurityFilter, you can use @Secured annotations or write access rules in configuration files [more examples in the doc](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#secured)